# My for loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was trying to shorten the code for returning "NO ANSWER" when one of my prompts was left blank in the code below:

```
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
var age = prompt("What is your age?");
var address = prompt("What is your email address?");
var credit = prompt("What is your credit card number?");
var social = prompt("What is your social security number?");

var arr = [name, age, address, credit, social];
var l = arr.length;

for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {

  if (arr[i] == "") {

    arr[i] = "NO ANSWER";

  }

}

alert("Your information is " + name + ", " + age + ", " + address + ", "    + credit + ",  and" + social + ".");
alert("Now the internet has all of your information. Have a nice day >:D");
```

however, the code doesn´t work. can someone tell me why?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't an acceptable problem description.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work? What do you expect and what do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop does work and works as expected. You need to use array `arr` while printing or using those input variables. That's because when you do  `arr[i] = "NO ANSWER";`, you actually set the array element to "NO ANSWER", not the original variables. See the following:

```js
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
var age = prompt("What is your age?");
var address = prompt("What is your email address?");
var credit = prompt("What is your credit card number?");
var social = prompt("What is your social security number?");

var arr = [name, age, address, credit, social];
var l = arr.length;

for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {

  if (arr[i] == "") {

    arr[i] = "NO ANSWER";

  }

}

alert("Your information is " + arr[0] + ", " + arr[1] + ", " + arr[2] + ", "    + arr[3] + ",  and" + arr[4] + ".");
alert("Now the internet has all of your information. Have a nice day >:D");
```

Comment: agree, this should work for your... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. It seems that you are updating arr but you are not printing arr to the screen.

```
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
var age = prompt("What is your age?");
var address = prompt("What is your email address?");
var credit = prompt("What is your credit card number?");
var social = prompt("What is your social security number?");

var arr = [name, age, address, credit, social];
var l = arr.length;

for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == "") {
    arr[i] = "NO ANSWER";
  }
}

alert("Your information is " + arr[0] + ", " + arr[1] + ", " + arr[2] + ", "    + arr[3] + ",  and " + arr[4] + ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried dry running the code with no address. following code works. The if statement need to change

```js
testarr = function () {
var name = 'xxx';
var age = 10;
var address;
var credit = 252525;
var social = 564654;
var arr = [name, age, address, credit, social];
var l = arr.length;

for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  if (!arr[i]) {
    arr[i] = "NO ANSWER";
  }
}

return arr;
//alert("Your information is " + name + ", " + age + ", " + address + ", "    + credit + ",  and" + social + ".");
//alert("Now the internet has all of your information. Have a nice day >:D");
}

var t = new testarr();
console.log ("Your information is " + t[0] + ", " + t[1] + ", " + t[2] + ", "    + t[3] + ",  and" + t[4] + ".")
```